# Store variables and functions in document

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Im building a webapp where i load the main page with its own javascript file in the index.html then the nav is calling all other pages in a div without a browser refresh using $.ajax and attaching specific script for each page in the div too with $.getScript.

Sometimes i needs to access a method declared in the main page javascript from within the div loaded javascript so what i generally do is attach the main method to document, exemple, instead of just:

```
let doThis = function(num){
// do your stuff
}
```

i do this

```
document.doThis = function(num){
// do your stuff
}
```

This way i can easily access it from any other javascript file loaded at different levels.

Thing is i feel its not a good practice, what would then be the good practice? or is it acceptable one?

Comment: If you need a global variable, just set a property on the window. There's no need to attach it to the document.

Comment: That's generally how you do it if you're not using bundler like webpack. This is okay when you're working on personal side project or just something small, IMO. You could also use all caps for the variable which reduces the chances of name clashing. Also, just append the functions/variables just in window, not document like hev1 mentioned in the above

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, not sure why i attach it to document instead of window actually, window make way more sens. But actually im using webpack, what is best practice then with webpack?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using any bundler,then '**Revealing Module Pattern**' can be used as a good practice here. This will allow the syntax to be more consistent and in this case, will make it easier to tell which of the functions can be accessed globally.

```
window.mainPageModule = (function () {

    var privateVar = "abcd",

    function privateFunction() {
        //Do some private stuff here
    }

    function publicSetValue(value) {
        privateVar = value;
    }

    function publicGetValue() {
        return privateVar;
    }


    // Reveal desired functions to public

    return {
        doThis: publicSetValue,
        getThis: publicGetValue
    };

})();
```

Then, to access the public function anywhere globally

```
mainPageModule.doThis("1234")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this sound way cleaner already. This being said, i'm using webpack already in this project, i guess then there is a better way with webpack?